# Change hyperlink based on date in Outlook 2013

Tags: vba, date, outlook

Every day our Helpdesk has to send out a report. That report needs to link to a website that displays that days statistics.

Example URL:

> http://hostname/dashboardname/date

Which would look like this:

> http://hostname/HelpdeskTickets/2015-03-18

Heres what I've tried:
First I looked into field code values and doing something like this

```
{HYPERLINK "http://hostname/HelpdeskTickets/{DATE \@ "yyyy-MM-dd"}"}
```

And this works, until you close the outlook message. If you don't have F9 to update the field code, and save and close the .msg file it will disappear leaving just the blank link without a date. If you hit F9 before closing it, it puts that days date into the field, however when you close and save it the field code disappears and leaves the date in place of the date field code. Also I noticed this problem doesn't happen in word. You can save and close a word file and it keeps the field codes.

Another thing I've tried is to use VBA to edit the links in the message body. So far nothing has actually worked.

The only thing that partially worked was taking the body of the document and using a string replace function on it. However this destroys all formatting and hyperlinks along with it.

I'm open to any ideas on how this can be achieved.

My main problem is that the people at the helpdesk can't seem to use anything that isn't fool proof. So having them press F9 before sending this email was actually scaring people that they wouldn't be able to do that.

Comment: Perhaps this would be easier to solve on the web site's end? Like, have a PHP script (or something) at `http://hostname/helpdesk/today` that redirects to today's page, and link to that? Of course, users wouldn't be able to use older messages that way.

Comment: And that's the main problem. Lets say reports go out Fridays-Sunday. Then on Monday the managers come in to see each of the reports, they click on the stats link and they by default if no date is provided are taken to yesterdays report, which is fine 90% of the time except if they don't read the reports over the weekend or every morning.

Comment: I see. I've never worked with VBA in Outlook before, but perhaps you can generate, and send, the entire E-Mail using a script, and have the helpdesk call the script using a button? Perhaps that circumvents the F9 issue (but then it may not, I'm really just speculating about something I know nothing about.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use VBA to edit the message body programmatically. It is not clear what code you used earlier, but the main ways are described below:

1. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) - a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. The HTMLBody property should be an HTML syntax string.
2. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model. So, the message body is represented by the Word Document.

You can read more about all possible ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: This is basically what I had done, minus the HTML part. I was using Body and when replacing the link it would break the HTML message turning it into text. Thank you so much!